# error_handler() or set_error_handler()

Tags: php, function

I practice an exam in the book (webbot, sspider, sscreen and scrapers) but it didn't go well.

the result is `:Warning: set_error_handler() expects the argument (BAD RESULT0) to be a valid callback`

```
<?php
    include("LIB/LIB_http.php");
    $page = http_get($target="http://123blablabla",$ref="");
    if($page['STATUS']['http_code']!="200")
        set_error_handler("BAD RESULT".$page['STATUS']['http_code']);
?>
```

Could someone help me how to use **error_handler()** or **set_error_handler()**?

Comment: did you read about error handlers before? ofcourse set_error_handler expects you to provide it a function, not a string

Comment: Did you read http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Answer (score 5):

There is no `error_handler` function. And the [set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) function is used to set a function / class that will handle errors when they happen.

It seems you are looking for the [trigger_error](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php) function

```
if($page['STATUS']['http_code']!="200") {
    trigger_error("BAD RESULT".$page['STATUS']['http_code'], E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you read about error handlers before? ofcourse `set_error_handler` expects you to provide it a function, not a string. Although error handler functions are not used conditionally inside `if` blocks, but for your code it would be like:

```
<?php
include("LIB/LIB_http.php");
$page = http_get($target="http://123blablabla",$ref="");
if($page['STATUS']['http_code']!="200")
    set_error_handler("yourErrorHandler");

function yourErrorHandler()
{
   echo "BAD RESULT;
?

?>
```

Comment: thank you for help :) you let me know I can use this 
    echo "BAD RESULT".$page['STATUS']['http_code'];